# Zoom in web page on android/iOS devices using CSS, JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to zoom in web page on load event, but I don't want to use `<meta>` tag for zooming web page.

Without using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

is there any way to zoom in webpage on Android/iOS devices using CSS, JavaScript or JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style as you want

if you want to change the zoom you can just add `zoom:80%;` for `body` or `html`
as will as you can add `font-size: 150%;` in your style for `body` or `html`

**iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPad mini in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**Apple Watch**

```
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}
```

**Samsung Galaxy S8+ Landscape Media Queries**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (orientation: portrait) { /* Your Styles... */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 740px) and (orientation: landscape) { /* Your Styles... */ }
```

**Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait and landscape**

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

**Laptops retina screens**

```
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {

}
```

> Note: Firefox is the only major browser that does not support Zoom

**So, you have to use this code below**

```
body { 
    zoom: 3; 
    -moz-transform: scale(3); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

> CSS zoom - supported in IE 5.5+, Opera, and Safari 4, and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [**Media Query**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
@media (max-width: widthOfDevice){
  body{
   zoom:SomeValue
}
}
```